# What is the equivalent of a windows active directory user in Openldap?

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, ldap, openldap

If I want to maintain a sync between active directory users with unix attributes enabled, and openldap, what would be the user's type that I have to create in openldap? I could see that a user in active directory has fields like "lastname", that translates to `sn` in openldap, where `sn` is a mandatory field for a `Generic: User Account` type in openldap, whereas it is not in AD. So when creating openldap users, what would be the closest template that I can use that resembles a normal active directory or group?

This `Generic: User Account` is a template that I came across in `phpldapadmin`

Answer (score 0):

Can you say what your use case is? both openldap and AD are x500 directories and can be connected over ldap/ldaps, are you migrating to Openldap or just trying to get directory authentication for an application or directory syncing to an application working?

here's the schema for openldap
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/schema.html

and here for AD
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms674984(v=vs.85).aspx

directory sync throws up all kinds of woes and you will have to map attributes like you have pointed our, if it's for an App I would investigate Shibboleth, if it's for server logins to Linux systems I would domain join them.